# Bing Application ID

Tags: bing, bing-api

I can't get application id at `Bing.com` for using their search api.
Please help, say me how I can get application id at Bing.com for using `bing search api` ?

Please write all steps, how you can get application ID?

Thanks.

Steps which i followed:
https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/legacy/developers/appids.aspx - go here

**2nd step**- https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44 
 `sign up` 
**3rd Step**
 https:// datamarket. azure. com  /account/  info
try use "Primary Account Key" then because in their documantation i find that primary cay i can use as application id. 
But place where i can register me App Id i can't find.

Comment: Please state what have you tried, and tag the language you are using, so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 3):

AppId is deprecated. Use access token as value or client key. For first look here:
https://github.com/openlabs/Microsoft-Translator-Python-API/blob/master/__init__.py

For last here:
[urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401 while querying using the new Bing API ( in azure marketplace )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728256/urllib2-httperror-http-error-401-while-querying-using-the-new-bing-api-in-azu)

Comment: github link is broken

Answer (score 0):

This Url Takes to register an app UI

https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications/

Comment: I`m new to those api and all. I got the same doubt. Do you have any idea to get app id for bing after creating developer user in bing?